# php chmod() not changing permissions

Tags: php, permissions, file-permissions, chmod, writable

I am having problems with a picture uploading script.

I know there are hundreds of the same questions, but I haven't found the one that would be work for me.

```
$upload_dir = "images/postcards/";
chmod($upload_dir, 777);
if (is_writable($upload_dir)) {
    echo 'The file is writable';
} else {
    echo 'The file is not writable';
}
```

This always returns that the file is "not writable"

I tried setting `chmod` to `0777` and `-rwxrwxrwx`. But result was always the same. Any Ideas?

Comment: in case of decimal `777` it is incorrect. you should always prefix with `0` check here [chmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The directory must be owned by the user invoking the script (typically `www-data`, `apache` or `httpd` if you're running the script in a apache/*NIX setup). A user can't set 777 permissions on directories it doesn't own.

See the note on the chmod() [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php):

> The current user is the user under which PHP runs. It is probably not
>   the same user you use for normal shell or FTP access. The mode can be
>   changed **only by user who owns** the file on most systems.

Answer (score 2):

First , open PHP error_report by adding two line on top of your code, see if there is a error coming from chmod:

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Make sure your WebServer has the permission to that directory, my guess is the WebServer don't have permission.

Comment: omg thanks so much for the error reporting thing. I was bashing my head against the wall trying to install stuff like Chrome Logger to get error reporting for php.

Answer (score 0):

I already had the same problem you can change the file's permission by this code :

```
<?php
$ftp_details['ftp_user_name'] = 'your ftp username';
$ftp_details['ftp_user_pass'] = 'your ftp password';
$ftp_details['ftp_root'] = '/public_html/';
$ftp_details['ftp_server'] = 'ftp' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
function ftp_chmod($path, $mod, $ftp_details) {
  extract($ftp_details);
  $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
  $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// try to chmod $path directory
  if (ftp_site($conn_id, 'CHMOD ' . $mod . ' ' . $ftp_root . $path) !== false) {
    $success = true;
  }
  else {
    $success = false;
  }

  ftp_close($conn_id);
  return $success;
}
?>
```

I didn't run this code but I think it's Ok and it will help you. 
tell me if your problems resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar troubles using chmod, although the file was owned by apache:apache (webserver user). In my case SELinux was getting in the way, disabling it made this clear:

> sudo setenforce 0

And the chmod works. Now on to figuring out how to make a SELinux exception for this case...
(and don't forget to enable SELinux, of course)

Comment: Improve your answer to make it more comprehensive.

Comment: This is the best answer for my specific case as i had the correct user and group set for the file.

Also on the theme of server configurations, i also found that setting a new `umask` for my webserver was the best option: http://serverfault.com/a/384922/185510