# Not able to change the file permissions using chmod in PHP

Tags: php, chmod

I want to **change the file permissions** to **chmod('file',0755)** but it is not working:

```
if(chmod("filepath",0755)){
    $fp = fopen("filepath", "r+");
if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {  // acquire an exclusive lock
                ftruncate($fp, 0);      // truncate file
                fwrite($fp, "Order no Synchronization\n");
                fflush($fp);   
flock($fp, LOCK_UN); 
} 
}
else{
    echo "Not able to change permissions";
}
```

The above code is not working for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169684/php-chmod-not-changing-permissions

Answer (score 0):

exec is used to run command directly on your terminal whith the help of this you can change forcefully permission to your file and directory

```
exec("chmod -R 755 $filepath");//$filepath is the path of your file or folder
```

Comment: No need for `exec()` if there is already functions in php for this! Also with no explanation this won't help much neither OP nor further readers