# Php - Chmod Not Working

Tags: php, chmod

I want to change the `chmod` values of the files from the user. But it does not work. My code is;

```
$chmod = "0777";
chmod($filename, $chmod);
```

I am entering `chmod 777`. But the chmod value of the file is `1411`.
I tried `chmod 0777`, `777`, `00777`. The results remain the same.

Comment: The most common reason this doesn't work is your webserver is running with user and group permissions that don't allow it to change the file.  When you log in, it's often with greater permissions than the webserver has.  Can you tell us who owns the file (user & group) and what user & group your web server is?

Comment: Does `$filename` contains the full path to the file? Does the user has proper permission to change permission on this file?

Comment: Not totally familiar with this functions but based on the comments on the php docs, you may need to put your mode number (0777) in the function `octdec()` instead of the quotes.

Comment: You php running as apache or php user, to be able chmod inside folder, you have to change the owner of this folder or add change permissions for specific user.  Example:  setfacl -m u:php:rwx myfolder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php chmod() not changing permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169684/php-chmod-not-changing-permissions)

Comment: Decimal integer `777` is equal to `1411` octal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem has to do with data conversion.

```
$chmod = "0777";
chmod($filename, octdec($chmod));
```

By just passing in the $chmod string it get converted 777 witch is not giving you want. octdec("0777") will output 511 that decimal will give chmod the value you want.

Comment: Yes! Thanks Bro.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file path and file name is correct! then try this

```
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0755);
```

Comment: It works this way. But I want to change it from the incoming.